# How do I get the execution time for Apache drill using rest api?

Tags: apache-drill

I want to get the total query execution time for Apache drill using some rest API or if any other method is available.

Comment: execution time for query right?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, execution time for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find information regarding execution time in Profile.

- To get the profiles of running and completed queries.

  Make a **GET** request to `http://drill_host:8047/profiles.json`
- To get the profile of the query that has the given queryid.

  Make a **GET** request to `http://drill_host:8047/profiles/{queryid}.json`

Check Drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rest-api/#profiles) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But can you please tell me from the json response what will be the execution time?

Comment: @VidhiRathore as per docs you  must be getting `"start":1447892599827,"end":1447892599950` (_these are timestamps_). you can easily convert this difference in minutes/seconds

Comment: Can we provide some filters in drill rest apis?

Comment: @VidhiRathore No. You need to filter useful data at your end.

Comment: Hi.. @ dev.. I have a question for you, Please help..  my problem is.. I am running multiple queries one by one in Apache Drill, Now what I want is.. To collect various performance metrics for the query like: HDFS bytes read/write, execution time. Do you have any idea that how can I collect hdfs bytes read and write for the queries, I have created the tables by csv files stored in hdfs... Please give me some idea that how can I get these metrics..

Comment: @VidhiRathore give me a sample query you tried via drill?

Comment: This is my one of the query....    SELECT org_id, sdp_wid, SUM(interval_value) as sum_value, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_wid FROM impala.interval_f WHERE interval_flag_cd=1 AND date_wid=20150105 GROUP BY  org_id, sdp_wid;                                                         I have put backtick for the reserved keywords

Comment: @VidhiRathore Go to : http://localhost:8047/profiles (_assuming drill is running on localhost_) click on the query. click on  `JSON Profile` under **Full JSON Profile** and check is this information relevant to you. You will get this JSON from REST call also as I told in the answer

Comment: I already have done this thing but from there I am not getting HDFS data

Comment: @VidhiRathore then you will not be able to get that data

Comment: Hi... Dev!!  Do you have any information about when can we have some improved version of APIs for Drill which can provide filters?

Comment: @VidhiRathore I don't think they are planning to improve Rest API with such features. Drill developers are best to answer this. Check [mailingList](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/), after subscription you can send mail to : user@drill.apache.org